# Excel calculated field - case when return value

Tags: excel, pivot-table, calculated-field

I'm trying to create a calculated field in a pivot table where it returns the total only if the category is meat (in this example anyways)

[image]

My attempt:

```
=IF('Food Category'="Meat",Count,0)
```

but when I add the calculated field as a sum I just get 0

Is this even possible? I know I could have 2 count columns, 1 for meat and 1 for fruit but I'd like to avoid that.

I'm using Excel 2010

Thanks

Comment: try replacing Count with 1, you haven't told it what to count. you just dropped an aggregate command into the formula.

Comment: =IF('Food Category'= "Meat",1,0),  =SUM(IF('Food Category'= "Meat",1,0) )  return 0 and  =IF('Food Category'= "Meat",SUM('Count'),0) gives an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it looks like this is not possible.

["See Here."](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-formulas-and-functions/533235-can-i-use-if-function-in-calculated-fields-in-a-pivot-table.html)

It appears In pivot table calculated fields, text values are seen as 0.

Best option would be to add a marker column. I.E. =if(A12 = "Meat",1,0) and set the calculated column to =if('Marker'=1,'Count',0)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=SUMIF(Food Category,"Meat",Count)
```

I am assuming **Food Category** and **Count** are named ranges for `A13:A20` and `C13:C20` respectively.

This should work even if **Food Category** and **Count** are column names.

Comment: Food Category and Count are column names.

Comment: @DDuffy - Thanks for letting me know.